# Zend Framework email content generation

Tags: email, zend-framework

With Zend_Framework, I wondered what is considered best practice for building up the content to send in a HTML email. In my case the content of the email that is sent is determined by a number of factors, for example the number of returned rows for a specific value in the database. Because of this it makes sense for me that the content is built up within the controller that sends the email which talks to the relevant database models and determines what the content should be. Where i'm not sure this works is that our designers and copyrighters will often want to adjust the copy in emails and this would then require them to make changes to a model or ask me to. Should i be handling this differently? Should i perhaps be storing HTML snippets somewhere containing the different text and then calling these somehow?

**EDIT** following from the answer by fireeyedboy, would it be acceptable to do something like this. Create a folder inside views called "partials" and use this to store text/html snippets that i can then call in where i need and replace special strings with dynamic values using regexp(or similar).

```
$nview = new Zend_View();
$nview->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/partials/');
$bodytext = $nview->render('response.phtml');
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText($bodytext);
// etc ...
```

e.g. in this context where two different templates could be used depending on variables returned from a Model:

```
// within a controller
public function emailAction()
{
    $images = new Model_ApplicationImages();
    $totimages = count($images->fetchImages($wsid));
    $acceptedImages = $images->fetchImages($wsid,'approved');
    $accepted = count($acceptedImages);
    $rejectedImages = $images->fetchImages($wsid,'rejected');
    $rejected = count($rejectedImages);
    $response = ($rejected == $totimages)?'rejected':'approved';
    $nview = new Zend_View();
    $nview->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/partials/');
    $content = $nview->render($response.'.phtml');
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setBodyText($content);
    // etc
}
```

Is there a more elegant way i can/should be doing this?

Comment: Can you clarify "that i can then call in where i need and replace special strings with dynamic values using regexp(or similar)"? Do you mean call in from within the view you are rendering?

Comment: added more details above

Comment: @snaken: I don't claim to be an expert on these matters, but I think you should ask yourself how different these views are. If they're significantly different then this might be the best solution. But if the views are similar, I would probably make one view with some conditional statements (that perhaps load partials, if necessary). What worries me a bit more is the rather verbose way of determining `$response`. Seems a bit redundant to call `fetchImages()` three times. I don't know how intensive this method is of course. Maybe you use lazy loading/caching mechanism already?

Comment: @fireeyedboy I totally agree about the fetchImages thing and i would certainly optimise this down the line. I agree that the two files are massively similar but i guess what i'm trying to do is prevent things like conditionals in views where possible. Maybe i'm taking this too far, would be interested to know what rules other people follow for what is and isnt acceptable in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is best practice, but what I did is extend Zend_Mail with methods like these:

```
setTemplatePath( $templatePath );
setTemplateHtml( $templateHtml );
setTemplateText( $templateText );
setTemplateArguments( array $templateArguments );
```

...then at some point in my overwritten`send()` I do:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath( $this->_templatePath );

foreach( $this->_templateArguments as $key => $value )
{
    $view->assign( $key, $value );
}

if( null !== $this->_templateText )
{
    $bodyText = $view->render( $this->_templateText );
    $this->setBodyText( $bodyText );
}

if( null !== $this->_templateHtml )
{
    $bodyHtml = $view->render( $this->_templateHtml );
    $this->setBodyHtml( $bodyHtml );
}
```

So to utilize this you would do something like:

```
$mail = new My_Extended_Zend_Mail();
$mail->setTemplatePath( 'path/to/your/mail/templates' );
$mail->setTemplateHtml( 'mail.html.phtml' );
$mail->setTemplateText( 'mail.text.phtml' );
$mail->setTemplateArguments(
    'someModel' => $someFunkyModel,
    /* etc, you get the point */
)
$mail->send();
```

In other words, with this you can let your designers and copywriters simply edit views (templates) like they are used to already. Hope this helps and has inspired you to come up with something funky that suits your needs.

**PS:**
Since you mention arbitrary data rows, you can, for instance, utilize the [partialLoop](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) view helper that comes with ZF for this. But you probably were aware of this already?

**PPS:**
I actually agree with chelmertz' comment about not extending Zend_Mail but wrapping it in my own component.

Comment: I don't think you should extend `Zend_Mail` but rather wrap it in your custom class with methods as `setTemplatePath()`. I base this on the guess that all those helper methods are still **using** (not extending) the `Zend_Mail::setBodyHtml()`- and `Zend_Mail::setBodyText()`-methods.

Nice solution otherwise.

Comment: @chelmertz: +1, I agree, actually. Good point. I thought about doing this at some point in the future, but hadn't come around to it yet. I should have made a note of this in my answer.